# Hash function value changing from day to day with same input

Tags: ms-access-2016, sha512

I have a simple hash function I copied from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA.  It hashes just fine.  I rehashed the text and it matched the saved hash.  I tried it again on a different day and the same text hashes to a different value.

```vb
Public Function SHA512(ByVal sIn As String, Optional bB64 As Boolean = 0) As String
    'Set a reference to mscorlib 4.0 64-bit

    'Test with empty string input:
    '128 Hex:   cf83e1357eefb8bd...etc
    '88 Base-64:   z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ...etc

    Dim oT As Object, oSHA512 As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte, bytes() As Byte

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oSHA512 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")

    TextToHash = oT.Getbytes_4(sIn)
    bytes = oSHA512.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

    If bB64 = True Then
       SHA512 = ConvToBase64String(bytes)
    Else
       SHA512 = ConvToHexString(bytes)
    End If

    Set oT = Nothing
    Set oSHA512 = Nothing

End Function

Private Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant

    Dim oD As Object

    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

      With oD
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set oD = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: ok, Why does it generate a different value on a different day?  I figured the question was implied.

Comment: Are you absolutely positively sure you hashed exactly the same text? I'd double check that.

Comment: Yes.  I had access email me the exact text that was entered in when it was working.  I copy/pasted it straight from the email and I typed it straight from the email just to make sure I didn't pick up a carriage return.

Comment: The *exact same* text could actually be different. Hash functions don't take *text* they take numbers id est bytes, which are different from encoding to encoding, given the same text. So I'd copy paste those texts to an online hash function (for example [here](http://onlinemd5.com/)) or so and check if they really are the same on the byte level.

Comment: doesn't `TextToHash = oT.Getbytes_4(sIn)` and  `bytes = oSHA512.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))` take care of that issue?

Comment: Please, just double check your input with another hash function to exclude the possibility that your hash function is wrong.

Comment: I ran the exact same text through an online checker and it generated yet a third.  What is wrong with my code that it won't generate the same thing on a different day
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.  The hash was hashing some random cache value.  Rewrote the passing of the value to the hash function.